# html pages flip by a link button with css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have my 3 html pages "index.html" "login.html" "register.html".

It is social site for practicing web development.

I like to flip,pop,slide up these pages by a button link.

something like this.

```
     http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html
```

I Just found 1 transition code but not flip,pop,slide up/down code.

So help me out how it be possible..

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
         $('body').hide().fadeIn('slow');
        });
   </script>
```

this is working. but is there any code something like this for fliping,sliding a page..

Thanks

Comment: are you using jquerymobile ui and js?

Comment: Inspect js and jquery codes using chrome inspector in page http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

Comment: link is just for hinting that I want to do something like this..!!